# How to click a link from a hover menu using Selenium Webdriver and Python?

Tags: python, selenium

http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/nikeid

I want to click on the 'Customize' nav link up in the top nav bar (so the one on the top, not the left) and then select Men's in the hover menu.

I can click on 'Customize', the hover menu than opens, but I am having trouble selecting Men's in that menu.  I have posted my code below.

```
    driver.get('http://www.nike.com/us/en_us/c/nikeid')
    # open Customize hover menu in top nav bar
    men_menu = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("li[data-nav-tracking=customize]")
    actions.move_to_element(men_menu).perform()

    # click Men's
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-nav-tracking=men] a[data-subnav-label$=Men's]"))).click()
```

How do I click on the Men's link with Selenium Webdriver?

Comment: I don't see `Men's` menu item inside the `Customize` menu. May be you meant "Men" link?..

Comment: Yes sorry, Men is what I am trying to click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just *fix your selector* to match the `Men` link:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-nav-tracking=customize] [data-nav-tracking=men] a"))).click()
```

Comment: It should go to here: http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-nikeid-shoes/7puZoolZoi3?ipp=120

Comment: If I manually click 'Customize' and then 'Men', it takes me to http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-nikeid-shoes/7puZoolZoi3?ipp=120, this is what i am trying to accomplish with selenium webdriver.

Comment: @Ben interesting. What do you mean by stopped working? Any errors, what is happening? FYI, here is what I'm executing and what is working for me: https://gist.github.com/alecxe/0c048b7f10b45a95790fdd6c372e985f.

Comment: I have resolved the issue.  The problem was that 'wait' and 'driver' were both defined in a different unit test, so I defined in this test as well and now it works.

Comment: thanks for the help though, you are like the selenium master of SO